# rails + attachment_fu: issue with files in directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, photoshop, attachment-fu

I use attachment_fu for my rails app. It's great for me.

However, the designer who works with me complains about it because it saves files in different directory. She said that she can't handle those files efficiently with Photoshop as they are scattered.

I tried to persuade her with the following reasons.

- We can avoid file name clash
- It's faster than when they are in the same directory

But I couldn't convince her. How would you? Or are you with her? If so, why?

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I think Adobe Photoshop has a built-in utility called 'Bridge' which allows easy asset management, might be worth having a look.